# node.js: transforming and returning passport.js profile upon authentication onto request object gives Promise { <pending> }

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, koa, passport.js

So I'm authenticating with passport.js like this:

```js
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    config.google,
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      done(null, transformGoog(profile._json, accessToken, refreshToken));
    }
  )
);
```

This is my `transformGoog function`

```
async function transformGoog(profile, token, refresh) {
  try {
   //querying database here 
 if (data) {
  return {
    uniqueID: data.uniqueID,
    provider: data.provider
  };
 } else {
   //constructing object to save to database here
   let newuser = new user(obj);
   await newuser.save();
   return {
    uniqueID: `google:${profile.id}`,
    provider: "google",
   };
 }
 } catch (e) {
 console.error(e);
 } 
  }
```

Here's where I `console.log` the request object

```
Router.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/auth/google" }),
  ctx => console.log(ctx.req.user) );
```

And I get `Promise { <pending> }`. I'm unsure on what this means or how to fix it.

Comment: you are trying to console.log the promise directly, you should use .then (because is still a promise, even if you are using async/await)

Comment: where would i use this `.then()` ?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**:
I modified this to await the request object like so

Router.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/auth/google" }),
  `async` ctx => console.log(`await` ctx.req.user) );